# What is the scope of environment variables defined in rc.local?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

Ubuntu 14.04

Since rc.local is executed as root, does this mean that environment variables of rc.local will be available to all the processes run as root? Why?

Please include references while answering.

Comment: On what OS?  `rc.local` does very different things on Linux, FreeBSD, and OpenBSD.  It probably does very different things on different Linux distributions.

Comment: @SatoKatsura edited

Comment: Doesn't Ubuntu 14.04 use `systemd`?  Then `rc.local` is a `systemd`-related thing.  But even assuming SysV init, environment variables set in a shell script are inherited only by programs that are descendants of said script, and only if they are `export`-ed.  The vast majority of `root` processes you get to see are descendants of `login` and / or some X display manager, which have nothing to do with `rc.local`.

Answer (score 4):

No, the scripts in `rc.local` are run as separate processes, which means they have no way to modify their parent's environment.

If you want to set environment variables system-wide, the place for that is `/etc/profile`.

[The FreeBSD `rc.local` documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc.local&sektion=8) mentions a convention that `/etc/rc.d/` scripts whose name ends with `.sh` will be sourced rather than executed independently.  I don't think this is portable to other platforms, though I could be wrong.

Comment: please point out the manual where it is mentioned that  the scripts in rc.local are run as separate processes.

Comment: I don't think it's explicitly mentioned (though "scripts" should suggest this interpretation; if the files were sourced by a shell, surely that would need to be mentioned!), but quick experimentation should easily bear this out.  It's also not a heavily standardized mechanism, so the precise documentation depends on your platform.  The FreeBSD manual page seems pretty exhaustive: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc.local&sektion=8